# Save information on div and retrieve that information onClick Event

Tags: reactjs

Let's say that i have an array of 5 integers
`[1,2,3,4,5]`
I iterate the array and i create 5 divs. On each div i want to have a onClick handler. So when i click on a div i want to retrieve the number.

What is the best way to store the info, so later i can retrive it from the handler function?

I have tried the following and it's working, but i am not sure if this is the best solution because in my app i will have a large amount of these divs.

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];

// make a closure
function onDivClick(id) {
    return () => {
      console.log(id);
    }
  }


return (

<div> 

{array.map( id => {
   return <div onClick={onDivClick(id)}> ... </div>
})

</div>
)
```

I have seen also the the html data attribute:

So i can store  and i can retrive it after with `event.target.getAttributes('data-id')`.

Is there other ways, and which is the best?

Comment: Questions of this kind are typically more suited to be asked on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not store it as state and retrieve it through the handler?  Seems like there's a more conventional way to achieve this.

Comment: @AttemptedMastery can you please provide an example? I know about the state, but i  am not sure how can i retrieve trhow the handler! How i will know which div is pressed to retrieve the corrent state?

Comment: It may be a while but when I find some time, I'll try to circle back!

Comment: @AttemptedMastery I will wait for your answer. Because i am not sure how to determine which div is pressed to retrieve the correct state!

Answer (score 2):

What you have right now is not okay. `{onDivClick(id)}` executes on every render.

Instead, add the `id` attribute directly to the div, and access it in the click handler.

Rewrite your click handler like so:

```
function handleClick(event) {
  let id = event.target.id;
  console.log(id);
}
```

and attach it to the div like so:

```
<div id={id} onClick={handleClick} />
```